# restore rpm to default installed version on RHEL

Tags: linux, yum, packages, downgrade, rhel-6

Is there a way to restore one single package back to the original version shipped with the RHEL OS?

A YUM downgrade just downgrades the package to the previous version located on the repository and is not what I want to do.  I figured I could do this with the repository that comes with the install cd, but I cant find it atm.  I have also tried to look up what the original version was, but I cannot find the specific version (including minor version) for RHEL 6.0 (not 6.4).

Comment: If no other package depends on the package you'd like to replace, then you probably could get away with doing `yum remove` followed by a `yum install --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=<glob_for_rhel_repos>`.

Comment: what do you mean by `<glob_for_rhel_repos>`? Wouldn't I need a repo whose has the latest version of the package as the same version as what came with my RHEL install? Is that what you mean by `<glob_for_rhel_repos>`?  If RHEL has repos for this very purpose, then that would be awesome!